# Oracle Query Last Week, This Week, And To this week

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I get the the date of last week?
example : 
today is 04 february 2015, 
i want query for last week which begin on 31 january until 01 january. 
this date is dynamic.  as example when today is 13 february 2014, last week is 01 january until 07 january. 
Thanks..

Comment: Makes no sense at all. Read your own question again, you have given arbitrary values which follow no logic. What do you mean by *31 january until 01 january*? In which planet?

Comment: i am sorry about my typo, i mean 31 until 01 february

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that the *31 january until 01 january* bit was a typo. Please look into the `NEXT_DAY` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions093.htm).
Example:

```
select trunc(to_date('13-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')) today, 
       next_day(trunc(to_date('13-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))-1, 'SUNDAY')-14 last_sunday,
       next_day(trunc(to_date('13-FEB-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY'))-1, 'SATURDAY')-7 last_saturday
from   dual;
```

Output (excuse the column formatting):

```
TODAY     LAST_SUND LAST_SATU
--------- --------- ---------
13-FEB-15 01-FEB-15 07-FEB-15
```

So you can pass in any date you want and it will still get you the sunday before, then the Saturday preceding.
Example for 25 Feb 2015:

```
TODAY     LAST_SUND LAST_SATU
--------- --------- ---------
25-FEB-15 15-FEB-15 21-FEB-15
```